# Image at background button

Tags: html, css, imagebutton

I have a little problem with the css file. I create a hmtl file and css file style and my idea is put in the background of the button form an image. When I use the css file doesn't work but I use the style parameter of the button is working fine, I do not understand.

My html/css code is this:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-image {
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url('/images/ok/login-login-on.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test - Log in</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <img src="images/ok/Logo.png" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
        <br></br>
        <div class="box-center">
          <form action="connectdb.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="txtbox-login-image" placeholder="Usuario" name="username" required autofocus>
            <input type="password" class="txtbox-password-image" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
            <!-- This option is not works -->
            <button class="btn-image" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <!-- This option is works -->
            <button style="background-image: url('images/ok/login-login-on.png'); width: 100px; border: 1px solid #fff; margin: 0 auto; display: block;">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Help me, please ;)

Comment: maybe your CSS file is in another directory, so you'd have to change the filepath in the url

Comment: please give some height to button in .btn-image css class

Comment: I have checked the path of the css file and it's ok!

Comment: I have added height: 100px; but it's the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button[type="submit"] {
    background: url('path/to/file');
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is not. I tried to put the image in the root path of the project without ../.../... only the name of the file and this copied at the current path.

Comment: If all else fails set your background-size: 100px; so that it resembles the working snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS file is in a directory at the same level as the `image` directory, your filepath has to be

```
background-image: url('../images/ok/login-login-on.png');
```